How do I obtain human-readable descriptions (keywords, phrases, etc.) for an embedding vector
I am using an embedding model to obtain vectors corresponding to a group of short documents. I then cluster related documents using these vectors.
For each cluster, I would like to describe to the user somehow the topics covered by the documents within it.
Are there models or techniques for obtaining keywords or phrases describing, for example, the centroid vector of the cluster? Essentially I want to reverse the embedding, but not to recover the original documents, only to come up with some human-readable indication of the topics associated with that region of the vector space.
